# Find upper limit of summation inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, summation

How is it possible, with correct calculus, to find the upper limit of a summation in an equation, this could for instance be: $\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{2^n}\tag{displayed}>0.99$

How would i go about finding x here with calculus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{x-1}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \cdot \dfrac{1-\frac{1}{2^x}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=1-\frac{1}{2^x}$$

Thus, you search some $x$ such that $1-\frac{1}{2^x}>0.99$. Therefore $0.01>\frac{1}{2^x}$, or $2^x>100$, which easily reduces to $x\ge 7$.

Answer (score 0):

For your particular problem it isn't hard because the sum is easy to find :

$$1-\frac{1}{2^x}>0.99$$

$$\frac{1}{2^x}<0.01$$

$$2^x>100$$
$$x \geq 7$$

It really depends on what your problem is . For complicated sums it's surely impossible to find $x$ just by using basic calculus .

Comment: Okay i understand, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider an 'horizontal' segment whose length is $1$, oriented from left to right. If you mark the partial sums ($0.5,0.75,0.875,\ldots$) wou will find that, in each step, you mark the middle point of the right most segment. So the sum will be greater than $0.99$ exactly when the term becomes lesser than $0.01$.

Comment: Yeah, i had that, however i wanted to do it with correct calculus, which you could maybe use in general for other summations aswell, however as i understand, this is not very eaily done, and practically impossible for complicated summations

Answer (score 0):

I would like to ask yet another question about this: is this kind of changing the summation equation to a regular equation in order to find the upper limit of an inequality only possible for a convergent summation, or can this be done to something like:

$\sum_{n=1}^x\frac{1}{n}$

Where the summation diverges off to infinity?